# What is this syntax in Java? I do not recognize it

Tags: java, syntax

This is a syntax question.

I was looking at some open source files and I met some syntax that I cannot recognize and I was hoping you could clear it up for me.

(This is taken from the Main.java in the Rhino debugger [here](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/debugger.html))

```
public static String[] processOptions(String args[])
    {
        String usageError;
        goodUsage: for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
            if (i == args.length) {
                return new String[0];
            }
            String arg = args[i];
            if (!arg.startsWith("-")) {
                processStdin = false;
                fileList.add(arg);
                String[] result = new String[args.length - i - 1];
                System.arraycopy(args, i+1, result, 0, args.length - i - 1);
                return result;
            }
            if (arg.equals("-version")) {
                if (++i == args.length) {
                    usageError = arg;
                    break goodUsage;
                }
                int version;
                try {
                    version = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    usageError = args[i];
                    break goodUsage;
                }
```

My question is what is `goodUsage`? what is the name of this syntax, and what is it used for?

Comment: Essentially, it means the author of the code is going to be attacked by a raptor:  http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Tenner, this is not the same as goto labels, java labels work only with loops. I guess the raptor doesn't care :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are labels. They are used to be able to break out of an inner block into a block that is not the one immediately surrounding it.

[Here is the relevant part of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7) that deals with labels.

You likely haven't seen it before because 99% of the time code can be rewritten to not use such a thing, and it's probably a sign that the method is doing too much.

(Also I should mention for anyone that happens to come across this question/answer from a search engine, it isn't *new* syntax - it's been around since the version one of the JLS.)

Comment: 100% of the time it can be re-written not to use them, 99.9% (Maybe that should be + .1%) the re-written version is more clear.

Comment: This description emphasizes the irony in the choice of label name.

Comment: Labeled breaks are often useful when you *must* have a `for()` loop several layers deep.  It often makes no sense to break out the inner `for()` loop into another method if you're iterating over a 2D or 3D array.

Comment: @jprete I would consider that case the 1%

Answer (score 4):

Makes me think of the following brain-teaser:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        http://stackoverflow.com
        System.out.println("Does it?");
    }
}
```

Does it compile?

Edit: SO's syntax highlighter does its job too good!

Answer (score 3):

This is just a branching statement and `goodUsage` is simply a label. See here:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 2):

It is called a labeled break.  It can be used to specify which loop you want to break instead of the innermost as it would normally do.  Here is a good example: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 1):

Its a label - the break statement supplies the label and this means it will be treated like a `goto` except that in Java a "break to label" will take you to the *end* of the block declared after the label.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a label. It lets you specify which loop you're breaking out of.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [labled break statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a label, see wikepedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax)